# How to change the frequency of an equalizer?

Tags: android, audio, equalizer

It is possible to change the frequency of the bands of an equalizer, or is only possible to use 60Hz 230 Hz 910 Hz 3600 Hz 14000 Hz?

Comment: Yes, it seems possible to define your own band frequency using android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.setBandLevel()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android audio effect limits to 5 bands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545571/android-audio-effect-limits-to-5-bands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about [android.media.audiofx.Equalizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html).

Different Android devices have different number of frequency bands, and you can set it freely between the supported ones, as the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer) says:

> [setBandLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#setBandLevel(short,%20short))(short band, short level)
>
> Sets the given equalizer band to
>   the given gain value.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **band -   short:** frequency band that will have the new gain. The numbering of the bands starts from 0 and ends at (number of bands - 1).
>
> **level - short:** new gain in millibels that will be set to the given band. getBandLevelRange() will define the maximum and minimum values.

This answer from [WoodyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653678/5791681) gives us some example code to get range supported for the device:

```
// New instance of equalizer (add it as a member of your class rather than a scoped instance like this)
Equalizer mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());

// Get the number of bands available on your device
short bands = mEqualizer.getNumberOfBands();

// Get the gain level available for the bands
final short minEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
final short maxEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];
```

You can find more opinions and help here: [Number of bands in Android Equalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682653/number-of-bands-in-android-equalizer/30477747#30477747)